# Cassandra Nodetool Status shows command not found

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.1

How to find the table size in Cassandra 2.8.2 community version.  nodetool cfstats is not working and in help as well nodestool is not avaiable.

Comment: can you please issue the query `show version` and report back what the output is?

Comment: what is "not working"?

Comment: Chris, I want to check the table size, but when I try with nodetool, it says command not found.Further when checked in "help" nodetool doesnot appear unlike other commands.

Comment: Hello Valerie,the output of show version is: cqlsh>show version                    [cqlsh 5.0.1 |Cassandra 2.2.8 | CQL spec3.3.1 | Native Protocol v4]

Comment: OK, thanks! Are you on Linux or Windows? If on Linux, can you issue `ls -al /usr/* | grep nodetool`? That is where it should be by default. If it's there, can you provide the output of an example nodetool command?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its on Windows, so is there any path to check the same on windows?

Comment: Any suggestions or help please..

Comment: user:~$ nodetool
nodetool: command not found
user:~$ cqlsh cqlsh: command not found, Please help